# is it necessary to bind a 'List' to a datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in which i need to show just one row. The values inside grid are editable. What i need to know is whether i can bind an object to the grid or need to add the object to a list and bind that list instead.
I am currently doing something like this:

```
class myclass
{
int id;
string name;
}
// some code here
myclass myObject = new myclass();
//initialized data in myObject
list<myclass> objectList = new list<myclass>();
objectList.Add(myObject);
// again some code
DataGridView myGrid = new DataGridView();
//added necessary columns
myGrid.DataSource = objectList;
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: I suggest you try to do it, then you'd answer yourself.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks.. it helped

Comment: For a `DataGridView` with custom information, I always found a `DataTable` with custom-defined `DataColumn`s, filled up with `DataRow` objects, to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` is usually the way to go to put custom data in a `DataGridView`. Here's a minimal example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Info");
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("index", typeof(Int32)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("data", typeof(String)));
for (Int32 i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
    DataRow row = symbolsTable.NewRow();
    row[0] = i;
    row[1] = myList[i];
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
this.myDgrv.DataSource = table;
```

Of course, this will not actually be linked to the original List; you'll have to handle that yourself.